# "Syntax error or access violation" - in migration from Schema:: facade, but statement executes without error

Tags: laravel-5.7, mysql-5.7

I have a migration written that executes just fine on my test database - did dozens of tests runs without issue. I run it on a clone of my prod database and all of a sudden I'm having all sorts of problems. I'm beginning to think its a database config or permissions issue, but I'm logged into this clone as root, so I'm not even sure where to start looking...

If I copy the mysql statement from the error (...and fix the missing data) the statement executes without issue.

```
ALTER TABLE `retail_items-tmp_09-10-2020` CHANGE original_inventory initial_inventory INT DEFAULT NULL;
```

The offending line:

```
Schema::table('retail_items-tmp_09-10-2020', function($table) {
     $table->renameColumn('original_inventory','initial_inventory');
});
```

The Error:

```
[PDOException (42000)]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-tmp_09-10-2020 CHANGE original_inventory initial_inventory INT DEFAULT NULL' at line 1
```

The migration:

```
    public function up()
      {
        /* 1. Backup Existing Tables */

          DB::statement('CREATE TABLE `retail_items-tmp_09-10-2020` LIKE `retail_items`; ');
          DB::statement('CREATE TABLE `ARCH__retail_items_09-10-2020` LIKE `retail_items`; ');

          DB::statement('INSERT INTO `retail_items-tmp_09-10-2020` SELECT * FROM `retail_items`; ');
          DB::statement('INSERT INTO `ARCH__retail_items_09-10-2020` SELECT * FROM `retail_items`;');

        /* 2. Update structure */

          Schema::table('retail_items-tmp_09-10-2020', function($table) {
            $table->renameColumn('original_inventory','initial_inventory');
          });

          Schema::table('retail_items-tmp_09-10-2020', function($table) {
            $table->integer('event_ID')->length(11)->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('event_ID')->references('event_ID')->on('events');
          });


        /* 3. Update structure that would have been destructive prior to step 3 */


          // When I had this piece of code included, it resulted in the same error "Syntax error or access violation..." this worked in testing, but throws errors on Prod, changed to DB:statement below with success.
          // Schema::table('retail_items-tmp_09-10-2020', function($table) {
          //   $table->smallInteger('flag')->unsigned()->nullable(false)->default(0)->change();
          // });

          $query = "ALTER TABLE `retail_items-tmp_09-10-2020` CHANGE `flag` `flag` SMALLINT(11) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL; ";
          DB::statement($query);
      }
```

I've been stuck on this for a bit, so any theories, places to look, etc would be appreciated.

(I have another migration that renames the temp table at the end of this. I have a few migrations and data operations that all together take ~ 10+ min to execute with the piece of code that I'm launching this with, so the temp tables are necessary to prevent downtime when launching in production)

Comment: Just throwing things out but it seems it doesn't like the dash. Usually it requires quotes when there is a dash and I see you have them, just to rule it out try it with an underscore there ( this might throw the error from the next dash ) and also maybe try double quotes instead of single.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still ended up having more troubleshooting/ other roadblocks on this issue, so this only removed one...

Even though they were properly quoted, I read a number of S.O. posts on the subject and as Webtect suggests I did end up simply removing ***all*** the dashes and things worked much more consistently and reliably. I'm still feel like it's a mystery as to ***why*** this happened because I've used hyphens in dates like this before - properly quoted - without issue. But this one sure threw me for a loop. I think I will entirely stop the practice of using hyphens in dated-table-names going forward. They seem to cause more headaches than the improved readability warrants.